Android Launcher Icon Not Showing After Successful Build in Flutter

image here I am developing a Flutter app, and I am having trouble getting the custom launcher icon to appear on Android. Despite following the usual process of generating the icon and confirming that the image file is correctly placed, the default Android icon is still being displayed.
Here are the details of what I've done:

I’m using flutter_launcher_icons to generate the icons.

My pubspec.yaml includes the following configuration:
flutter_launcher_icons:
  android: "launcher_icon"
  ios: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
  min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
  web:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
    background_color: "#hexcode"
    theme_color: "#hexcode"
  windows:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
    icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
  macos:
    generate: true
    image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"


<application
        android:label="appName"
        android:name="${applicationName}"
        android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">


I have already tried flutter clean and rebuilding the APK, but the custom icon still isn't showing.

I’ve also tried uninstalling and reinstalling the app on my device and cleared the app cache, but it still shows the default Android robot icon.


I’ve verified the image path and ensured that the icon is in PNG format, square, and meets the size recommendations.
Any idea why the launcher icon is not showing correctly on Android?
Environment:

Flutter version: 3.16.9

flutter_launcher_icons: v0.13.1

Android SDK: C:\\Users\\...





Check the following directories to ensure that the icon files have been generated correctly:
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-/launcher_icon.png

When you run the following command:

dart run flutter_launcher_icons

A folder named mipmap-anydpi-v26 will be created in:
android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-anydpi-v26
Delete this folder, then run your application
And you're all set!

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.

Very nice find!
I am not sure why this happens but I just came back to using this package after 2 years, It didn't happen to me back them. Indeed this is the temp solution.

It worked very nicely.

Thank you! this issue has wasted nearly an our of my life!

If your icon is black after build successfully, maybe you can try it:
image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"

android: true
ios: true
image_path_android: "assets/images/icon.png"
min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
adaptive_icon_background: "#ffffff"
adaptive_icon_foreground: "assets/images/icon.png"

Remember check your image path too!

It seems like the issue is with the configuration in your pubspec.yaml file. The flutter_launcher_icons package expects the configuration to be under the flutter_icons key, not flutter_launcher_icons. Here's how you can fix it:

Update your pubspec.yaml configuration: Replace flutter_launcher_icons: with flutter_icons:. Your updated configuration should look like this:
android: "launcher_icon"
ios: true
image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
min_sdk_android: 21 # android min sdk min:16, default 21
web:
  generate: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
  background_color: "#hexcode"
  theme_color: "#hexcode"
windows:
  generate: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"
  icon_size: 48 # min:48, max:256, default: 48
macos:
  generate: true
  image_path: "assets/images/icon.png"



Regenerate the launcher icons:
Run the following commands in your terminal:
flutter pub get 
flutter pub run flutter_launcher_icons:main


Clean and rebuild your project:
flutter clean
flutter build apk


Verify the icon files: Ensure that the launcher icon files have been generated in the correct directories:


android/app/src/main/res/mipmap-*/launcher_icon.png


Double-check the image path: Confirm that the image at assets/images/icon.png exists and is accessible. The image should be:

In PNG format
Square (equal width and height)
Of adequate resolution (recommend at least 1024x1024 pixels)


Confirm AndroidManifest.xml configuration:Your AndroidManifest.xml seems correct, but just to be sure, it should include:

<application
    android:label="appName"
    android:name="${applicationName}"
    android:icon="@mipmap/launcher_icon">


Uninstall the existing app before reinstalling: Sometimes, cached icons might still display. Uninstall the app from your device completely before reinstalling it.


Look at https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons,
